# Changing the URL/URI of pagination in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using the pagination class in Codeigniter to page out some info from my database.

It's all working perfectly, however, i'm trying to tidy up the URLs that people use to access the pages.

Currently, i'm pulling out the offset from the URL and have set it to 20 results per page:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page/20
```

So if you go to (in this instance) page two, it starts from db entry 20.

The trouble is that firstly, since i've set it to 20 results per page, it means I get odd URLs like http://www.mysite.com/page/60 which would be page 4.

Secondly it's a double figure which i'd like to tidy up.

Basically want I want to do is set the URLs to look like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/page/2
http://www.mysite.com/page/3
http://www.mysite.com/page/4
```

etc...

I set the use page numbers to TRUE, but the trouble is it then sets the offset to 2, 3, 4 etc when it should be 20, 40, 60.

Any ideas? I was thinking of some kind of calculation in the model to work out how many entries it should offset based on the individual page number from the URL (when use page numbers is set to TRUE). I can't seem to get it right though...

Comment: OK I managed to figure it out I think. What I did was set use_page_numbers to true. Then when I get the offset from the URL, I multiply it by 10, then mins 10 from it and then double it. So for example page 4 (where the desired offset would be 60) I do 4*10 = 40. Then mins 10 to make 30 and double it to get 60. Simple maths I think, probably didn't need to ask on here haha.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer and mark it as accepted for the benefit of future visitors :)

Comment: I can't answer my own question until my rep gets to 100.

Comment: Ah, yeah - forgot about the rep limitations.

Answer (score 2):

In codeigniter number in url means: row per page
So if you need to change **per page** number with **page number** change your code like this:

**Controller**

```
class news extends CI_Controller{
    function index($page = 'page', $page_number = 0){
         $row_per_page = 20; // define page per page

         // for example if page number == 4 then offset 80
         $offset = $page_number * $row_per_page 

         // we need to request data from database
         // we need this query "SELECT * FROM `mytable` limit 80,20"
         // offset = 80 AND per page = 20
         $this->db->get('mytable', $offser, $row_per_page); 

         $this->load->library('pagination');

         // you can change this url by URI Routing and other solutions.
         /*
          change application/config/routes.php to nice url
          $route['news/page/(:num)'] = "news/index/page/$1";

         */
         $config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/index.php/news/index/page/';

         // Change $count_of_rows with your query num_rows you can use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
         $config['total_rows'] = $count_of_wors;
         $config['per_page'] = $row_per_page; 

         $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

         echo $this->pagination->create_links();
    }

}
```

This is very simple. Enjoy CI

Comment: I realize that this is old, but your math is off. An offset of 80 would be page 5, not page 4. To get the proper offset, it would be ($page_number - 1) * $row_per_page.